# VBA Programming for Microsoft Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

While implementing a macro via Visual Basic Editor, i got an error "Compile Error: Procedure Too Long".........i wanted to know why is there a limit to the size of the macro and is there any way to increase the allowed size. My macro is pretty big (based on around 150 different cases) and because of this error i will have to divide the task among 8 macros approximately. Is there anyway around it?

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: can you show an example of code within each of the 150 case statements?

Comment: There is no way to increase the size limit. You'll need to refactor your code.  This is probably a good thing (though you might not see it as that!) - if you have a procedure which exceeds the limit then most likely it does need to be refactored. If you post some example code as suggested by scott I'm sure you'll get input on how to shorten your code.

Comment: known issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa264541 - you will have to break it down into separate sections.

Comment: IIRC there is a string length limitation on both the length of a procedure, and the modules themselves.  These are legacy limitations having to do with the fact that originally, strings were limited to a 16-bit length field (so max was either 32,767 or 65,565).  VBA is 10 years obsolete now, so that's not going to be fixed.  My own experience has been that you want to stay well away from those limits to prevent all kinds of strange compile and storage bugs and corruption.  So best to "refactor" (make more modules and then call subroutines/functions in those modules from your root procedure).

Answer (score 2):

You can speculate on the logic for limiting the text size of a subroutine - maybe they don't think it is necessary to have subs that long - maybe they gain some slight performance boost by doing it - maybe it is just a purposeful limitation to prevent people from recording ridiculously long macros. But in any case it is probably better from a scripting/programming perspective to not have monstrous subs anyways. And with loops you shouldn't need to have subs with that much text in them. So my hypothesis is that they wanted to prevent people from relying on recorded macros when it would be better and more efficient to use loops. But it's just a hypothesis. Good Luck.

Comment: VBA inherits most of what it is from VB, which long predates it (and the macro recorder). I doubt that the length limitation has anything to do with MS trying to keep us from recording crazy-long macros. Apart from that, the sheer frustration of trying to record anything that long and actually have it work, even once, would be enough to deter even the most determined/brain-faded. ;-)